# How to handle multipart POST using a URI template of form /prefix/{suffix} in OpenRasta?

Tags: openrasta

I'm trying to handle a POST of a multipart document in OpenRasta with a URI template declaration of /content/{contentId}, but it fails. The configuration is

```
ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType<Content>().AtUri("/content/{contentId}").HandledBy<ContentHandler>().RenderedByAspx("~/Views/ContentView.aspx").And.AsJsonDataContract();
```

The handler method is as follows:

```
public OperationResult Post(string contentId, IEnumerable<IMultipartHttpEntity> entities) {...}
```

I'm using the following curl command to test

```
./curl -v -F myPartName=@./hello.txt http://localhost:10247/content/id-1
```

The POST works fine if I remove "{contentId}" from the URI template and modify the handler accordingly.

Any ideas on how to resolve? Log file follows below. Thanks --Roland

```
4-[2011-10-10 02:27:47Z] Verbose(0) Starts pre-executing the request.
4-[2011-10-10 02:27:47Z] Verbose(0) Incoming host request for http://localhost:10247/content/id-1
4-[2011-10-10 02:27:47Z] Verbose(0) Adding communication context data
4-[2011-10-10 02:27:47Z] Warning(0) Contributor call for BootstrapperContributor had a null Action.
4-[2011-10-10 02:27:47Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor HttpMethodOverriderContributor.OverrideHttpVerb
4-[2011-10-10 02:27:47Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
4-[2011-10-10 02:27:47Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor AuthenticationContributor.AuthoriseRequest
4-[2011-10-10 02:27:47Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
4-[2011-10-10 02:27:47Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor UriDecoratorsContributor.ProcessDecorators
4-[2011-10-10 02:27:47Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
4-[2011-10-10 02:27:47Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor ResourceTypeResolverContributor.ResolveResource
4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) Rewrote path.
4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Start(1) Entering OpenRastaRewriterHandler: Rewriting to original path
    4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Start(1) Entering OpenRastaIntegratedHandler: Request for http://localhost:10247/content/id-1
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) Incoming host request for http://localhost:10247/content/id-1
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) Adding communication context data
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor HandlerResolverContributor.ResolveHandler
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor OperationCreatorContributor.CreateOperations
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) Created operation named Get with signature ContentHandler::Get(String contentId)
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) Created operation named Post with signature ContentHandler::Post(String contentId, IEnumerable`1 entities)
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor OperationFilterContributor.ProcessOperations
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) Found 1 operation(s) with a matching name.
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) Found 0 operation(s) with matching [HttpOperation] attribute.
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) No resource or no uri name. Not filtering.
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor OperationCodecSelectorContributor.ProcessOperations
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Information(0) Operation ContentHandler::Post(String contentId, IEnumerable`1 entities) selected with 2 required members and 0 optional members, with codec MultipartFormDataKeyedValuesCodec with score 1.5.
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor OperationHydratorContributor.ProcessOperations
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Information(0) Operation ContentHandler::Post(String contentId, IEnumerable`1 entities) was selected with a codec score of 1.5
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Information(0) Loaded codec OpenRasta.Codecs.MultipartFormDataKeyedValuesCodec
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Information(0) Codec supports IKeyedValuesMediaTypeReader. Processing parameters.
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) Seeking to next available part
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) Skip the preamble. AtPreamble was True.
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) not null
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) Preamble found: True of size 0
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) not null
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) not null
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) not null
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) Skip the preamble. AtPreamble was False.
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) Preamble found: False of size 0
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) not null
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) not null
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) Seeking to next available part
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) not null
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) not null
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) Key myPartName was not successfully assigned.
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) Key myPartName was not successfully assigned.
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor OperationInterceptorContributor.WrapOperations
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor OperationInvokerContributor.ExecuteOperations
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:51Z] Verbose(0) Ignoring constructor, following dependencies didn't have a registration:OpenRasta.OperationModel.Interceptors.IOperationInterceptor[]
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in OpenRasta.DLL
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Error(0) An error of type System.InvalidOperationException has been thrown
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Error(0) System.InvalidOperationException: The operation is not ready for invocation.
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Error(0)    at OpenRasta.OperationModel.MethodBased.MethodBasedOperation.Invoke() in C:\Users\hochmuth\Repositories\openrasta-core\src\OpenRasta\OperationModel\MethodBased\MethodBasedOperation.cs:line 56
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Error(0)    at OpenRasta.OperationModel.Interceptors.OperationWithInterceptors.<Invoke>b__0() in C:\Users\hochmuth\Repositories\openrasta-core\src\OpenRasta\OperationModel\Interceptors\OperationWithInterceptors.cs:line 47
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Error(0)    at OpenRasta.OperationModel.Interceptors.OperationWithInterceptors.Invoke() in C:\Users\hochmuth\Repositories\openrasta-core\src\OpenRasta\OperationModel\Interceptors\OperationWithInterceptors.cs:line 52
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Error(0)    at OpenRasta.OperationModel.OperationExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 operations) in C:\Users\hochmuth\Repositories\openrasta-core\src\OpenRasta\OperationModel\OperationExecutor.cs:line 14
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Error(0)    at OpenRasta.Pipeline.Contributors.OperationInvokerContributor.ExecuteOperations(ICommunicationContext context) in C:\Users\hochmuth\Repositories\openrasta-core\src\OpenRasta\Pipeline\Contributors\OperationInvokerContributor.cs:line 29
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Error(0)    at OpenRasta.Pipeline.PipelineRunner.ExecuteContributor(ICommunicationContext context, ContributorCall call) in C:\Users\hochmuth\Repositories\openrasta-core\src\OpenRasta\Pipeline\PipelineRunner.cs:line 192
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Error(0) Aborting the pipeline and rendering the errors.
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Error(0) An error has occurred and the processing of the request has stopped.

Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: The operation is not ready for invocation.
   at OpenRasta.OperationModel.MethodBased.MethodBasedOperation.Invoke() in C:\Users\hochmuth\Repositories\openrasta-core\src\OpenRasta\OperationModel\MethodBased\MethodBasedOperation.cs:line 56
   at OpenRasta.OperationModel.Interceptors.OperationWithInterceptors.<Invoke>b__0() in C:\Users\hochmuth\Repositories\openrasta-core\src\OpenRasta\OperationModel\Interceptors\OperationWithInterceptors.cs:line 47
   at OpenRasta.OperationModel.Interceptors.OperationWithInterceptors.Invoke() in C:\Users\hochmuth\Repositories\openrasta-core\src\OpenRasta\OperationModel\Interceptors\OperationWithInterceptors.cs:line 52
   at OpenRasta.OperationModel.OperationExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 operations) in C:\Users\hochmuth\Repositories\openrasta-core\src\OpenRasta\OperationModel\OperationExecutor.cs:line 14
   at OpenRasta.Pipeline.Contributors.OperationInvokerContributor.ExecuteOperations(ICommunicationContext context) in C:\Users\hochmuth\Repositories\openrasta-core\src\OpenRasta\Pipeline\Contributors\OperationInvokerContributor.cs:line 29
   at OpenRasta.Pipeline.PipelineRunner.ExecuteContributor(ICommunicationContext context, ContributorCall call) in C:\Users\hochmuth\Repositories\openrasta-core\src\OpenRasta\Pipeline\PipelineRunner.cs:line 192
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Verbose(0) Pipeline is in RenderNow mode.
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor OperationResultInvokerContributor.RunOperationResult
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Information(0) Executing OperationResult OperationResult: type=InternalServerError, statusCode=500.
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor ResponseEntityCodecResolverContributor.FindResponseCodec
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Information(0) Selected codec HtmlErrorCodec out of 2 codecs for entity of type ServerErrorList and negotiated media type text/html; q=0.5.
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor AuthenticationChallengerContributor.ChallengeIfUnauthorized
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Start(1) Entering PipelineRunner: Executing contributor ResponseEntityWriterContributor.WriteResponse
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Verbose(0) Codec HtmlErrorCodec selected.
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Start(1) Entering ResponseEntityWriterContributor: Generating response entity.
                4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Verbose(0) Setting Content-Length to 2159
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Stop(1) Exiting ResponseEntityWriterContributor
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Verbose(0) Writing http headers.
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Verbose(0) Writing http header Content-Length:2159
            4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Verbose(0) Writing http header Content-Type:text/html
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Stop(1) Exiting PipelineRunner
        4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Information(0) Pipeline finished.
    4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Stop(1) Exiting OpenRastaIntegratedHandler
4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Stop(1) Exiting OpenRastaRewriterHandler
4-[2011-10-10 02:27:52Z] Verbose(0) Request finished.
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1f68) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: If you add the debug log to the question we may be able to help to know what's going on.

Comment: Hi Serialseb, I added the debug log to the original question. Thanks --Roland

Answer (score 1):

From the log, you can see that the multipart codec is being used in key/value processsing mode. In that mode, the content of the multipart is being parsed instead of assigning the IEnumerable, and that certainly is an issue with that codec.

I've added a bug to fix this issue at https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-core/issues/32

In the meantime, you can let the multipart codec deserialize the content as needed (which you can use by simply mapping a DTO or input parameters to the names of the form entities, OpenWrap will let you assign form data into standard properties and IFile or Stream for files).

Alternatively, depending on your needs, you can unregister the key/value mutlipart codec by overriding the dependency registrar and let the object-only registration work as normal.

Comment: Thanks Serialseb! I quickly tried the second approach, overriding the dependency registrar, and that worked. This seems like a good work-around for us right now. Looking forward to the actual fix. Thanks for the very quick response! --Roland